# Next Auth TypeError: Invalid URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, next-auth

I keep receiving when I run my project - Nextjs. I think it about Next Auth, but don't actually know what to do. I am using version 4.3.1

Need help with next-auth

[image: 1]

I have tried changing my next-auth version but no. Yet when I deployed in vercel, it went through

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have NEXTAUTH_URL set in your .env file you will get this error. However vercel will work as next-auth automatically sets it when deployed to vercel.

https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#nextauth_url

If you do have NEXTAUTH_URL set then my best guess is the url is wrong in some way. Maybe missing http://?

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed NEXTAUTH_URL in my env file. It worked.

Comment: It been about 4 hours now searching for help